# need definition of android studio debug icon

Tags: android-studio, debug-symbols

I've searched on Intellij online help site, have Googled the question above, and have searched previous questions on this site and have not found out what the little green glasses icon signifies in the variables section of a debugging session of android studio.  Can anyone tell me what it means?  In my case it is right before a scanner session, but not sure that is relevant. I don't have enough points yet to include a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out for general completion symbols
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html
and you can find a lot of symbol by follow this step (in Mac)

1. Go to Preferences (press ⌘ + ,)
2. On left tab, find Keymap and click it (or you can go on Menu and Toolbars too).
3. and expand the "other" folder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: unfortunately, that list of icons doesn't show the pair of glasses. and, i'm on a pc so the Mac stuff won't help me either.

Comment: Sorry for long response, did you mean green glasses? its mean "Watches", maybe its a feature to debugger from android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I believe they are 'watches', i.e. expressions that Android Studio/Intellij evaluate and display to you at every breakpoint because they think it'll be useful info. You can also add your expressions manually in the Watches pane in addition to the auto-generated ones. Or at least that's my best guess after reading this:)

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debug-tool-window-watches.html